How do you type check injected child component in svelte?
I was wondering if you could do a type check on a child component that is injected into a parent component in Svelte?
So for example, if I wanted to do the following, but where the child is only allow to be of the type of the ChildRight component and not of another component like ChildWrong.
I have researched a little and concluded that you can either use <slot> or <svelte: component> to inject another component. A solution to either method would be useful.
Using slot
Parent.svelte
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: red;">
    <slot></slot>
</div>

App.svelte
<script>
    import Parent from "./Parent.svelte"
    import ChildRight from "./Child-right.svelte"
    import ChildWrong from "./Child-wrong.svelte"
</script>

<Parent>
    <ChildRight />
</Parent>

Using svelte:
Parent.svelte
<script lang=ts>
    export let childElement;
</script>


<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: red;">
    <svelte:component this={childElement} />
</div>

App.svelte
<script>
    import Parent from "./Parent.svelte"
    import ChildRight from "./Child-right.svelte"
    import ChildWrong from "./Child-wrong.svelte"
</script>

<Parent childElement={ChildRight} />

So just to clarify, the following should give a type error
Using slot
<script>
    import Parent from "./Parent.svelte"
    import ChildRight from "./Child-right.svelte"
    import ChildWrong from "./Child-wrong.svelte"
</script>

<Parent>
    <ChildWrong />
</Parent>

Using svelte:component
<script>
    import Parent from "./Parent.svelte"
    import ChildRight from "./Child-right.svelte"
    import ChildWrong from "./Child-wrong.svelte"
</script>

<Parent childElement={ChildWrong} />

I have come by one solution using svelte:component, where I hardcode the type check. This does not seem like a preferable solution though
<script lang=ts>
    import ChildRight from "./Child-right.svelte"
    export let childElement;
</script>


<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: red;">
    {#if childElement === ChildRight}
        <svelte:component this={childElement} />
    {:else}
        <p>ERROR IN CHILD TYPE</p>
    {/if}
</div>


You cannot type-check slot contents, they can contain any content or no content at all.
If you pass the class as property, you could check the type in the parent component but at that point you might as well just use the component directly and only accept properties as input.
